# Most google related apps stopped working

Tags: google-apps

My phone was doing perfectly fine until the browser app stopped working. I thought it wouldn't affect other apps as well. But then most of my google related apps: chrome, youtube and google play cannot be accessed. I've tried clearing caches, force stop, disabling those apps. Didn't work either. Last resort I came up with was the factory reset. Became worse. Now I just don't know how to handle it. I've lost so many important information in the phone. :( Please help.

Comment: We'll need more info, such as device model and OS version.

Answer (score 0):

Try install Google Service Framework from [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-services-framework/)

also possibly try a wifi connection

if the above fails possible solution reflash stock rom

Comment: Where did OP mention that they lack the framework?